# How to run mac terminal command in lotusscript

Tags: macos, lotus-notes

For windows my lotusscript code will run the following code

```
Dim objShell, returnValue
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
returnValue = objShell.Run("SourceTree D:\Repository\MyProject\")
```

Assuming the same syntax (SourceTree [Folder path]) also run in Mac Terminal, how do I run the command using Lotusscript in Mac ?